# MatchIt: Optimal matching fails

Tags: r, matching

I've been using the [MatchIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/) package in R to do treatment versus control matching, and I can't get the optimal matching to work with my own dataset.

If I run the following code:

```
m.out <- matchit(match_formula, data=stats, method='optimal', distance='logit', ratio=2)
```

where the formula is

```
treatment ~ t_1 + t_2 + t_3 + t_4 + t_5 + t_6 + t_7 + t_8 + t_9 + 
t_10 + t_11
```

then I end up with the error

```
Error in fullmatch.matrix(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls = ratio, : omit.fraction must be NULL or numeric between -1 and 1
```

I couldn't find anywhere in the `matchit` method to specify an omit.fraction variable or what that even does. Is there any way to get around this bug and perform optimal matching?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `matchit` is using the `fullmatch` function from from the `optmatch` package. See the help file from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out!

Because I had more control than treatment units, `optmatch` was unable to assign all control units to at least one treatment, which led to the error above. The solution was to switch the control and treatment populations and use a matching ratio of 1 in order to match all control units to a treatment unit.

Bonus: the optimal matches were an even better fit than the "nearest neighbor" matches, which I guess is to be expected.

Comment: That's so strange. I feel that `optmatch` should know that many controls are to be matched to a few treated units. Thank you for posting!

Comment: Yeah it was totally the opposite of what I was expecting! I guess I need to read up more on matching in general.

Comment: How counterintuitive! Worked for me. Thanks for posting.